# Maxim/Microchip (can't tell) IC Identification

Tags: identification, pinout

Part No. is 024 134A. Says Japan M5 on the bottom, visible through a hole in the PCB, not pictured. It is a memory lockout chip for Gameboy, it disables the SRAM when the Gameboy is powered down. I'm looking for a pinout. [image: Picture of IC]
Edit: This photo is of Tetris DX. Pokemon Yellow marks the IC as 001 134A. is there a difference? Also, google turned up nothing.

Comment: With 8 pins, a DMM will give you the pinout faster than you'll find a datasheet most likely.

Comment: @MattYoung How would i do that? Really, I'm looking for a tertiary power source pin. (5v rail is primary, battery is secondary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That would be an MM1134](http://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/304/MM1134-pdf.php) as indicated [on this site.](https://www.insidegadgets.com/2011/03/19/gbcartread-arduino-based-gameboy-cart-reader-%E2%80%93-part-1-read-the-rom/)

The manufacturer seems to be Mitsumi rather than Maxim or Microchip.  Makes sense for a japanese product.

It is indeed used to disconnect the SRAM when power is off.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake got the wrong chip first time. The chip is a 134A the leading 001 and 024 could be manufacturer codes, batches etc.
You are correct in saying it is a RAM power down chip. After a little search on google I've come across [this basic sketch](http://www.devrs.com/gb/files/134a.gif) which is what I think you're after

Comment: You are looking at the wrong part.  The one in question is the 8 pin part higher up in the picture.  The pinout you linked to is for the much larger one below it.

Comment: You're probably right about the first point - _...date or batch numbers._ But you identified the wrong chip.